How to insert timestamp with tokio_postgres?
I have a field created timestamp without time zone and a u32 variable with timestamp number.
The code is something like this:
use tokio_postgres::NoTls;

let mut params: Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)> = vec![];
let mut query = String::from("INSERT INTO tokens (created) VALUES ($1)");
let timestamp:u32 = 123;
params.push(&timestamp as &(dyn ToSql + Sync));

let client = DB_POOL.get().await?;
client
    .execute(&query, &params)
    .await?;

And got error
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: ToSql(7), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: Timestamp, rust: "u32" }) }


Timestamp doesn't map to u32. There's a table showing type correspondence in the docs: https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.12/tokio_postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html.

@STerliakov I know. Thank you for the table

The correct way was to use SystemTime type to store timestamp.
use std::time::{SystemTime};
let timestamp: SystemTime = SystemTime::now();
params.push(&timestamp);

